# Get Variant ID Product Shopify and insert fetch post

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-api

Hello How can I get a product ID and set it in the fetch solution in the ID field:
**'id':**

What would be the code to insert in that area?

```
$("#purchase").click(function(){
  var addData = {
    'id':, /* ID Variant */
    'quantity':1
  };

  fetch('/cart/add.js', {
    body: JSON.stringify(addData),
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With':'xmlhttprequest',
    },
    method: 'POST'
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    /* we have JSON */
    console.log(json)
  }).catch(function(err) {
    /* uh oh, we have error. */
    console.error(err)
  });

  
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should to add Attribute with name variant-id  to the #purchase button you don't need for the product_id to add the item to the cart and get the variant id by `document.getElementById('purchase').getAttribute("variant-id ");`

and in the button `#purchase <button id='purchase' variant-id={{variant.id}} >`